overflow:hidden with scroll-behavior:smooth works weird in chrome
I've generated a list of cards(div) and two buttons each side for the horizontal scroll manipulation.
DOM
<div
  style={{
   position: "relative",
   width: "100%",
   border: "1px solid black",
   height: "300px",
  }}
>
 <StyledButton
   style={{ left: -20 }}
   onClick={() => scroll("left")}
   disabled={prevButtonDisabled}
 />
 <CardListContainer ref={containerRef}>
   {Array(10)
     .fill(null)
     .map((_, i) => {
       return <StyledDiv>{`${i}번째 Div`}</StyledDiv>;
     })}
 </CardListContainer>
 <StyledButton
    style={{ right: -20 }}
    onClick={() => scroll("right")}
    disabled={nextButtonDisabled}
 />
</div>

Style
const CardListContainer = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 135px;
  gap: 20px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
`;


Full code example: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/kn2clq

The issue is that when I scroll left and right via two buttons, some weird thing is observed. What makes me confused is that the issue is not represented in Safari, Firefox and even Chrome Canary. It only represents in the latest chrome.
I could solve the issue after adjust the style like below:
/* overflow-x: hidden; */
overflow-x: auto;

scrollbar-width: none;

Wonder what's the reason of this issue. Any insight?
